# Reuse of jspdf data

Tags: javascript, jspdf

How can i reuse the data created as jspdf-object to other pages in the same pdf-document without rewriting everything for each page? Also i need to adjust one line only on each page. Se comments below.

```
$("#pdfBtn").on('click', function(){

  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(5, 5, 'Specific text for page 1');
  // Reusable data
  doc.text(5, 10, 'This is reusable text');
  doc.text(5, 15, 'More reusable text');

  doc.addPage();
  doc.text(5, 5, 'Specific text for page 2');
  // Here i want to reuse the data from page 1

  doc.addPage();
  doc.text(5, 10, 'Specific text for page 3');
  // Here i want to reuse the data from page 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Just make a function containing the data and call it in every new page.

```
$("#pdfBtn").on('click', function(){

  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(5, 5, 'Specific text for page 1');
  addBody();

  doc.addPage();
  doc.text(5, 5, 'Specific text for page 2');
  addBody();

  doc.addPage();
  doc.text(5, 10, 'Specific text for page 3');
  addBody();

  function addBody() {
    doc.text(5, 10, 'This is reusable text');
    doc.text(5, 15, 'More reusable text');
  }
});
```